# listing the values of an array in c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, winforms

I have a Windows Form with two textboxes and two buttons.  The textboxes are named txtVisited and txtAnswer.  The buttons are `Visited?` and `Exit`.  I want to input a city into the first textbox and have it check the array for a match.  If there is a match, I want to display the text that it has been visited and it's position in the array.  If it does not find a match, I want it to display the text "not visited." I have copied all the code I have so far.  Any help would be much appreciated.  I'm still really new to c# so I may or may not understand your answer.  So bear with me.  Sorry in advance.

```
    namespace Array
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnVisited_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] CityName = {"Columbus", "Bloomington", "Indianapolis",
                "Fort Wayne", "Greensburg", "Gary", "Chicago", "Atlanta", "Las Vegas"};
            bool visitedbool;
            int Subscript;
            string QueryCity;
            QueryCity = txtState.Text.ToUpper();
            int Subscript =0;
            visitedbool = false;

            while (visitedbool = true)

            if (CityName(intsubscript).ToUpper= QueryCity)
            {
                visitedbool = true
            }

            else
            { 
                Subscript =  Subscript +1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know what happened to the other guy's answer, but he helped me through this process.  I just want to extend my deepest gratitude for his effort.  He never got impatient with me and I'm a tard when it comes to c#. He gave me the code to get it working. I just had to add the code for the text boxes.  `namespace Project
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnVisited_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            string[] CityName = {"Columbus", "Bloomington", "Indianapolis",
            "Fort Wayne", "Greensburg", "Gary", "Chicago", "Atlanta", "Las Vegas"};
            string queryCity = txtState.Text;
            int position;
            string city;

            if (CityName.Contains(queryCity))
            {
                position = Array.IndexOf(CityName, queryCity);
                city = txtState.Text;
                txtAnswer.Text = "You have visited" +" " + queryCity + " " + position;
            }
            else
            {
                txtAnswer.Text = "You have not visited this city yet.";
            }
        }`
```

Comment: I think his name was cogeneto or something similar.  He deserves all of the credit.

Comment: Just a small comment - instead of using `Enumerable.Contains()` and `Array.IndexOf()` you can use only `Array.IndexOf()` and check `if( position >= 0)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to by Enumberable.contains().  I do know the code posted above works for what I was trying to accomplish.  Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: Other than the fact the array is case sensitive(i.e. if I type bloomington it says not visited)

Comment: please see the implementation here http://pastebin.com/8n0ReYgY. It should also solve the problem with case sensitive input.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That resolved my issue with case sensitivity.

Comment: Ok, so I have a dumb question.  What is the item and why is it =>?

Comment: The part `item => item.ToLower() == queryCity` is called a `lambda expression`. It's a shorthand notation for a method that, in your case, is used to test whether the argument of the method (namely `item`) is the lowercase value of the searched city.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It's still all over my head. This is my second c# class at the Purdue College of Technology.

Comment: I guess I'm just not sure why the notation is =>? Is that just how the notation for Lmabda Expressions work?

Comment: Since the original poster's answer is gone for whatever reason. I will accept the answer I posted with the rework with RePierre.  Thank everyone so much for all the help you've given to me.  You have no idea how much I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var idx = Array.IndexOf(CityName, QueryCity);
if (idx  != -1)
{
    // display QueryCity and idx
}
else
{
    // display "not visited"
}
```

Comment: So where would I put the values of my array at?  Thank you very much for your quick response.  Like I said I'm really new to c#.